# How to compare two strings in C ignoring the new line character?

Tags: c

I'm studying C programming, I know in C `strcmp` is used to compare two strings, but the comparing always contains the new line character, I want to ignore it. I know I can remove the new line character and then compare them, but is there any function that ignores the new line character automatically?

Answer (score 2):

This is one of those cases where it's easier to open code the function. I've made it test for equality strictly (i.e. not alphabetise), though that would be a relatively easy change.

Try this, which should actually do what the original questioner asked:

```
/* Compare two strings s1 and s2, assuming s1 is terminated
 * by \n or a NULL, and s2 is terminated by a NULL. A match
 * returns 0, a non-match returns 1.
 */
int
strcmpst1nl (const char * s1, const char * s2)
{
  char s1c;
  do
    {
      s1c = *s1;
      if (s1c == '\n')
          s1c = 0;
      if (s1c != *s2)
          return 1;
      s1++;
      s2++;
    } while (s1c); /* already checked *s2 is equal */
  return 0;
}
```

Interestingly this wasn't particularly elegant to do with a `for` loop. More elegant answers appreciated.

A more generalised routine to compare two strings where either can be terminated by a `\n` or a `NULL` (not quite what you asked) would be:

```
/* Compare two strings s1 and s2, assuming either is
 * terminated by \n or a NULL, A match
 * returns 0, a non-match returns 1.
 */
int
strcmpnl (const char *s1, const char *s2)
{
  char s1c;
  char s2c;
  do
    {
      s1c = *(s1++);
      s2c = *(s2++);
      if (s1c == '\n')
          s1c = 0;
      if (s2c == '\n')
          s2c = 0;
      if (s1c != s2c)
          return 1;
    }
  while (s1c);          /* already checked *s2 is equal */
  return 0;
}
```

Another less efficient route (assuming s1 is terminated by `\n`) would be:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>
int
strcmpst1nl2 (const char *s1, const char *s2)
{
  int s1len, s2len;
  s1len = strlen (s1);
  s2len = strlen (s2);

  /* check strings are equal length without \n */
  if (s1len - 1 != s2len)
    return 1;

  /* we know s1len > 0, as s2len would be -1, so this is safe */
  if (s1[s1len - 2] != '\n')
    return 1;

  return bcmp (s1, s2, s1len - 1);
}
```

Comment: I think your answer is a little bit too custom, considering only the possibility that one of the 2 strings contains the termination character. Also, it won't work properly for some implementation of the new line (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3267311/what-is-newline-character-n/3267323#3267323)

Comment: That's what the question actually asked for ('but the comparing always contains the new line character'). However it would be trivial to fix the open coded version (which is the one I recommend) to treat `\n' as a terminator in either string by adding another `if` statement. I will modify the answer to show how.

Answer (score 1):

You should first write a function that computes the length of the string, in which both the standard termination character and the endline character terminate the string. In doing so, I suggest you both check Line Feed and Carriage Return character (check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3267323/2436175))
Then, you check that **both strings** have **same length according to the previous definition**.
If yes, you further check the string with strncmp (and using the found length as third parameter).

Answer (score 0):

A function like the following could be used instead of `strcmp()`.  It does the same thing, but ignores one (possible) trailing newline on the second string.  It doesn't modify the strings.

```
int my_cmp(const char *str1, const char *str2)
{
  int r,n;

  /* Get length of str1, which is also the index of the 1st additional 
   * char in str2 
   */
  n = strlen(str1);

  /* Compare the first n chars */
  r = strncmp(str1,str2,n);

  /* If 1st n chars match, make sure next char in str2 is either the null char
   * or a newline followed by the null char.  Otherwise, return -1 since str2 is
   * longer (making str1 "less than" str2)
   */
  if ( !r && str2[n] && (str2[n] != '\n' || str2[n+1]) )
    return -1;

  return r;
}
```

Here's another one that ignores all newlines anywhere in either string:

```
int my_cmp(const char *str1, const char *str2)
{
  const unsigned char *a, *b;

  /* loop over both strings */
  for (a = str1, b = str2; ; a++, b++) {
    while (*a == '\n') a++; /* skip newlines in str1 */
    while (*b == '\n') b++; /* skip newlines in str2 */

    /* If we reach the end of either string (or both), one of
     * the if's below will terminate the loop */

    /* return if we're at end of both strings */
    if (!(*a || *b)) 
      return 0;

    /* positive return when str1's char is greater than str2's 
     * (or at end of str2) */
    if (*a > *b)
      return 1;

    /* negative return when str1's char is less than str2's 
     * (or at end of str1) */
    if (*a < *b)
      return -1;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Of course, if you just need to ignore a single trailing newline it's easy to strip it off anyway (just locate it and overwrite it with `'\0'`)...