# Using '\n' while writing code in C

Tags: c

I'm a beginner in C, and I wrote this code. I wonder why this doesn't work with a '\n' but it still works with '\t'. Can someone please help me? Thank you.

```
int count=0;

while(1)
{
    key[count]=getch();

    if(key[count]=='\n') //The condition works well when a '\t' is used instead
    {
        break;
    }

    else
    {
        printf("*");
    }

    count++;
}
```

Comment: This won't compile, because `key` isn't defined.  And what do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: The code you have doesn't even compile

Answer (score 2):

[I would say it depends on the operating system.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3267311/what-is-newline-character-n)

Notice that when you hit enter you hit "\r\n" and not only "\n".

Try running your code with input from a file, I bet it would work.

Also, if you are interested about `\n` then have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3267311/what-is-newline-character-n) too.