# python3 ValueError: could not convert string to float , value = float(value) is not valid

Tags: python, string, numpy

I have a problem with a command of python. I want my program to read a specific line from my file, and here I haven't problem. The problem is when I have to convert the line in a float (I need of float to calculate some equation). My program is:

```
f=open('coeff.txt')
lines=f.readlines()

k1=lines[0]

k1 = float(k1)


k2=lines[1]

k2 = float(k2)


k3=lines[2]

k3 = float(k3)

k4=lines[3]

k4 = float(k4)
```

And the file coeff.txt is:

```
1.2*1e-1   

6.00*1e-34

1.13*1e-4

6.9*1e-16
```

that is 1.2*10^(-1)  , 6*10^(-34), 1.13*10^(-4), 6.9*10^(-16)

and I get the error:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: '6.00*1e-34\n'
>
> (obviously that this error is referred to each line.

Can you help me, please?

Comment: Clean your question

Comment: what is inside that text file?

Comment: here is a useful answer, that shows what are floats and what not. Maybe you just need to format your string before you convert it to a float. https://stackoverflow.com/a/20929983/8411228

Comment: If you're in control of what is in coeff.txt, it'd probably be better to drop the "*1" before the "e".  That's a non-standard notation.  Much better to just say `1.2e-1`, `6e-34`, `1.13e-4`, and `6.9e-16`, IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

Python doesn't know how to interpret `'6.00*1e-34\n'` as a float. You will have to clean your data before you can actually use it.

Eventually, you will want to have each line in a format like this:
`6.00e-34`

Looking at it closely, it seems like the only differences are the `\n` at the end of the line, and the `1*` in the middle.

You can get rid of the [newline character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3267311/what-is-newline-character-n) at the end of the string (`\n`) by calling the [`.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) method, and [replace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) `*1` with an empty string to get to the above format.

```py
val = '6.00*1e-34\n'
cleaned_val = val.strip().replace('*1', '')
print(float(cleaned_val))
>>> 6e-34
```

Edit: It seems like the presence of the newline character doesn't really matter - so you only need to replace the `*1` part of your string. I'm leaving it in anyway.

Comment: thank you so much!! i have resolved my problem!!  in fact now i have wrote my file "coeff.txt" as :
  0.12
6.00e-34
1.13e-4
6.9e-16    
   and now it work

Comment: I just tested converting a string to float with a \n inside and it just works. So your hint is not necessary. But it will of course also works, when you strip it.

Comment: @federico-fede Glad to help! Don't forget to mark as answered if there are no further questions.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the operator *

Comment: thank you so much!! i have resolved my problem!!  in fact now i have wrote my file "coeff.txt" as :
  0.12
6.00e-34
1.13e-4
6.9e-16    
   and now it work

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22398140)

Comment: Looks like this has solved the problem @vahdet. So it might also be an answer.
Can you explain, why the operator * was the problem?

Comment: open() return a string(default) or bytes(b) objects, when float() receives a string it should contain a decimal number positive or negative and accept ONLY '+' or '-' sign operators.