# What actually while(character !='\n'); this \n syntax meaning?

Tags: c, arrays, string, do-while

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    char line[81],character;
    int c;
    c=0;
    printf("Enter Text.Press <Return> at end \n");
    do{
        character=getchar();
        line[c]=character;
        c++;

    }while(character !='\n');
    c=c-1;
    line[c]='\0';
    printf("\n%s\n",line);
}
```

Comment: you might need to read about [what is a newline character -- '\n'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3267311/what-is-newline-character-n)

Comment: You'll run into problems if you encounter EOF before you get a newline — which is possible, though not common.

Comment: @SaifBashar If some of the answers below has helped you out, don´t forget to accept one or ask for more details if you did not understand it yet.

Answer (score 1):

The `'\n'` is a **new line** character, as I am sure you allready know. New line is a character like anyone else, for example `'a'`,`'b'`,`'c'`,`'\t'` (tab), a space `' '` etc.

So `while(character !='\n')` means as long the character is **not a newline**.

Answer (score 1):

`\n` is the newline character, made by the press to Enter/Return.

With

```
do{
 ...
}while(character !='\n');
```

you have a `do-while` loop with a condition to proof if the character in `character` is a newline which is appended after the proper input. The loop breaks if `\n` is inside `character` and makes no further iterations.

Note that since it is a `do-while` loop, the loop´s body got at least one time walk through.

The concept of

```
do{
    character=getchar();
    line[c]=character;
    c++;

}while(character !='\n');
```

is to read a character at each walkthrough and to write the characters subsequent into the elements of the array `line`, including the newline character.

Note that the appending of `\0` after the loop

```
c=c-1;
line[c]='\0';
```

is important since this character terminates a proper string!

Also note that the return value of `getchar()` is of type `int` to hold the erroneous `EOF`. You should change the type of `character` to `int` and later proof this value to make sure no error has occurred, which is important. The assignment to the array is no problem with an object of the type `int` since `char` is relative to `int`.